# ¿Como almacenar variable en JavaScript hasta recargar pagina?

Tags: javascript, variables, dom

Mi pregunta se basa únicamente en si existe la posibilidad de introducir una variable a través de un `prompt()`  y que esta se guarde sin importar cuantas veces se corra el código después, y se elimine solo al recargar la pagina o eliminarla manualmente con otra interacción del usuario. Lo que en realidad quiero es que si la variable se introduce por primera vez, no vulva a pedirla al usuario.

He tratado con `sessionStorage()` que por falta de experiencia no concluyo si es mi culpa y no se utilizarlo o no se puede. Y utilizando algo como `if (variableX === null){ variableX = prompt("Introduzca el nombre.");}` (solo es un ejemplo), pero nada me da resultados. a continuación dejo un código de ejemplo.

La idea es que cada vez que el botón sea presionado la variable "nombre" se guarde y se reutilice la próxima vez al ejecutar `trigger()`.

```js
function trigger() {

  var nombre = prompt("Introduce tu nombre");

  var suma = 0;

  document.getElementById("expl").innerHTML = " ";

  do {

  var number = prompt("Introduzca un numero para la suma.");

  console.log(number);

  if (Number(number) == number) {

    number = Number(number);
    suma = suma + number;
    console.log(suma);

  }else {

    if (number != null){

      var hola = alert(number + " No es un nuemero valido.");
      console.log(hola);

    }

  }

} while (number != null);

  document.getElementById("expl").innerHTML += nombre + ", el resultado es: " + suma;

}
```

```html
<button onClick="trigger()">Haz clck para empezar</button>
<p>Click en cancelar para ver la suma</p>
<p id="expl"></p>
```

Comment: Y como lo pusiste con session storage?

Comment: Coloque algo parecido a `sessionStorage.setItem("nombre", prompt("Introduce tu nombre").value;); if (sessionStorage.getItem("nombre") == ""){var nombre = sessionStorage.getItem("nombre"); }` como dije no se si es correcto pero me pareció lógico en el momento.

Comment: Amigo, todas la variables locales como `var` o `let` se generan automaticamente cada vez que se recarga la pagina

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar cookies, a diferecia de sessionStorage que se elimina al terminar la sesión, osea al cerrar el navegador o la pestaña; las cookies puedes almacenarlas con un periodo que tu establezcas hasta su posterior destrucción.

crear una cookie (max-age son segundos)

```
document.cookie = "nombre=variableValor; max-age=7200";
```

para leer una cookie existen distintas formas, yo suelo utilizar esta función con expresiones regulares

```
function readCookie(name) {

  return decodeURIComponent(document.cookie.replace(new RegExp("(?:(?:^|.*;)\\s*" + name.replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=\\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$"), "$1")) || null;

}
```

Comment: La verdad es que no estoy familiarizado con la cookies y no entiendo muy bien la respuesta y como a una variable que contiene un `prompt()` es "almacenable" y utilizable para el fin requerido, es decir, darle el valor a la misma y que no se ejecute el `prompt()` nuevamente para que el programa utilice este mismo valor hasta que la cookie sea eliminada. Gracias por la repuesta, pero si pudieses darme un ejemplo con mi código, seria ideal, si no es mucho pedir por supuesto.

Comment: hola, mira te dejo un ejemplo de como crear una cookie, como leerla y como eliminarla (con un boton) https://repl.it/@pangea/cookiesJS

Comment: Vale, ya entiendo como funciona esto, gracias por el ejemploQQ